# How to specify some parameters using WithParameter method and let autofac resolve unspecifed parameters

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a class receiving an interface and a string parameter in constructor:

```
public MyClass(IService service, string config) : IMyClass
```

In Autofac, the interface is registered:

```
builder.RegisterType<Service>()
       .As<IService>()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

`MyClass` is also registered with `WithParameter` method for the string parameter:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyClass>()
       .As<IMyClass>()
       .WithParameter("config", parameters["Config"]);
```

But how to pass the already resolved object of `IService` interface into the `MyClass` constructor?

I was expecting that the above used registration of `IService` is enough, but when the `WithParameter` method is used, I obviously need to declare all parameters same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was expecting that the above used registration of IService is
>   enough

Your assumption is correct.

> when the WithParameter method is used, I obviously need to declare all
>   parameters same way.

You do not need to pass `service` parameter together with `config` parameter. The container will resolve it for you.

The following two lines are enough -

```
builder.RegisterType<Service>().As<IService>().InstancePerRequest();

builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().As<IMyClass>()
   .WithParameter("config", parameters["Config"]).InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: Is it enough? Because when I remove the IService from constructor, it gets resolved ok. But when I put it back, I get "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'UsersController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor" which means that MyClass cannot be resolved.

Comment: It should be enough. Look at this sample : https://dotnetfiddle.net/x0xBcn. By the way, the error message doesn't look at an *Autofac* message. Did you configure the *DependencyResolver* of ASP.net MVC (see http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#quick-start for an example)